# Synchronize files from current year to FTP from Windows

Tags: batch-file, ftp, synchronization, robocopy

I have been using a batch file or two to copy newer photos and files across to a mapped drive, `WD MyCloud`, a bit like this:

```
robocopy "D:\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll" "X:\Media\Digital Images\2018\Photos" /XF *.mp4 *.png *.dng /MAXAGE:20180101 /MINAGE:20181231 /S /E /XO /R:0 /W:0 /MT:32
```

This one obviously limits files to those in `2018`. I have many others!

I have found this way to be slow with the `MyCloud` and I would like to use `FTP` instead.

I have seen posts on `PowerShell` as a potential solution but cannot get my head round if that would do what I need.

Is there a good, effective way to replace `RoboCopy` commands and switches with something that can use `FTP`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/).

Use a batch file like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "put -filemask=*>=2018-01-01 ""D:\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll\*"" ""/ftp/path/""" ^
    "exit"
```

---

If you want to synchronize files (upload only those files that are not present of FTP yet), add [`-neweronly` switch to the `put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#neweronly).

Or, if you need more flexibility, you can also use [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "synchronize remote -filemask=*>=2018-01-01 ""D:\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera Roll"" ""/ftp/path""" ^
    "exit"
```

---

Some references:

- [Automating file transfers to FTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [WinSCP time constraints](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*